# Grafana randomly changes Strings from Data Source?

Tags: sql, string, grafana, identifier, grafana-variable

I am currently working on a project where I want wo collect some data from a specific Machine.
With that data there comes an Identifier which identifies the Object that's worked on, so it's kind of clear that this has to be an accurateley displayed Number.
It is currently saved as a String in an MS SQL Database.

Query:
[Click here to see a snippet of my SQL generated Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmaZJ.png)

However, Grafana seems to have a problem with displaying the Identifier - and only the Identifier - the right way:

[Click here to see a snippet of my Grafana Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnwU6.png)

Just to visualize what my problem is:

```
Identifier displayed in SQL:      252010387528000096
Identifier displayed in Grafana:  252010387528000100
```

I've already checked for this behaviour on my other Grafana Boards but I couldn't seem to find out what causes the problem.

My SQL Query I used in both SQL and Grafana:

```
SELECT
  [time],
  [Index],
  [Identifier],
  [WaitingJamTime],
  [WaitingPartMissing],
  [ProcessingTime],
  [RunningInTime],
  [RunningOutTime],
  [Station],
  [Result],
  [ScanQualiSerial],
  [ScanQualiGehaeuse]
FROM
  [048115_PSDC]
WHERE
  [Station] = '458106101' AND
  $__timeFilter(time)
ORDER BY
  time desc
```

Comment: 1.) Use query inspector to see what DB returns to Grafana (is it really  252010387528000096?)2.) How is formatted `Identifier` in the table panel - did you ue explicit String formatting?

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I just used the Query inspector to have a look at the values Grafana acually receives. To my surprise, Grafana received the right values, but it changes them because of the "formatted data" option. When I turn the option off, it seems to display the Identifier correctly, but I'm still trying to find a way to save these changes to the dashboard panel. Any more advice?

Comment: Well, I found it. Thanks a lot, you really helped me @JanGaraj

Comment: It will be polite to provide answer here.